# Encrypt with with certificate on string

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption, certificate

My application signs some documents when manually creating them. For that, it has a private and public RSA keys manually generated and supplied by the user. So by now, they are stored on a config table in DB.
The program also has a functionality for bulk-creating those documents at the DB, and I'm using a stored procedure for that.

I'm trying to use the Encryption functions of SQL server, but I can't make them work with a public key stored in the config table (as a varchar(max))
EncryptByCert always expect a cert id stored in a sys table and generated by the DB.

I would like to do something like:

```
DECLARE @RSAPublicKey VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @RSAPublicKey = xRSAPublicKey FROM MyConfigTable
print EncryptByCert(@RSAPublicKey, 'Hello')
```

Comment: Signing and encryption are two different concepts. Furthermore, it does not make sense to get a private key from your user. It is perfectly possible to store a cert in a string, but you don't specify the format. Certificates themselves are (ASN.1 encoded DER) binaries, so a variable length binary format makes more sense. It may be easier to retrieve the certificate from the database using a programming language like Java or C# and perform the signing/encryption from there.

Comment: Thanks owlstead, I get your point. Unfortunately that's a requirement from the Portuguese tax agency and they're "stupidly" concrete on their specifications. User may supply a private and public keys stored as text so they can pick random chars while working with documents, for example.
I think the men in black they got are completely wrecked.